# PouchDB: What to expect on a remote url of the database?

Tags: html, pouchdb

I am trying to create an offline first mobile app using PouchDB as a database.

After creating an instance of PouchDB, it says to create a remote database, I should provide the remote database url.

```
var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://sampleurl.com/sampledb");
```

Now, my question is, what should I do to setup the URL (*in this case: http://sampleurl.com/sampledb*) that I provided to run a remote database from PouchDB?

Are there any setup needed to do or I just provide a URL and I am good to go?

Thanks. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide the URL and you are good to go! Now all of the PouchDB API is available for you to communicate with the remote database.

There are some useful options and configuration available when creating a new instance of PouchDB, such as setting headers and default authentication. You can read more about that here: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database

Comment: If auth is needed you can specify authenticantion options on the URL itself, or you can make sure the user has a valid session.